# How to do custom URL and Breadcrumb in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize the WooCommrece Breadcrumb and URL for My WooCommerce based website.

My website is running on the WooCommerce. I am facing the issue to customize the Breadcrumb and URL to short from the too long. when I am visiting any product or category page then the URL will be very long and also the Breadcrumb will be very long due to long name of the category and the slug of the category.

So, I need the solution like I will add the alternative category name for the Breadcrumb in woocommerce and add the alternative slug for the URL.

can this help me in WooCoommerce? 
can I customize the WooCoomerce product URL and Breadcrumb?

Comment: What did you tried till now ? any code ?

Comment: Yes, I am working on it. And I am very close to complete this thing... After that, i will update here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done developing for the Breadcrumb by the alternative title.

My code is below..

```
/*
* Custom title for category
*/
add_action('product_cat_add_form_fields','custom_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 1);

//admin side extra field
function custom_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
?>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="alternative_title"><?php _e('Alternative Title', 'store-front-child'); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="alternative_title" id="alternative_title">
    <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter Alternative Title for Breadcrumb', 'store-front-child'); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}

add_action('product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'custom_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 1);
//admin side extra field when edit
function custom_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$alternative_title = get_term_meta($term_id, 'alternative_title', true);
$alternative_slug = get_term_meta($term_id, 'alternative_slug', true);
?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="alternative_title"><?php _e('Alternative Title', 'store-front-child'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="alternative_title" id="alternative_title" value="<?php echo esc_attr($alternative_title) ? esc_attr($alternative_title) : ''; ?>">
        <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter Alternative Title for Breadcrumb', 'store-front-child'); ?></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}

add_action('edited_product_cat', 'custom_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 1);
add_action('create_product_cat', 'custom_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 1);
//save alternative title to database
function custom_save_taxonomy_custom_meta($term_id) {
$alternative_title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'alternative_title');
update_term_meta($term_id, 'alternative_title', $alternative_title);
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_change_breadcrumb' );
//filter the woocommerce breadcrub text for category
function custom_change_breadcrumb( $crumbs ) {
global $post;
echo $post->id;
$new_crumb_array = array();
if( !empty( $crumbs ) ):
    foreach ( $crumbs as $crumb ):
        $new_crumb = array();
        $new_crumb[0] = $crumb[0];
        $new_crumb[1] = $crumb[1];
        $cat = get_term_by( 'name', $crumb[0], 'product_cat' );
        $alternative_title = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'alternative_title', true );
        if( !empty( $alternative_title ) ){
            $new_crumb[0] = $alternative_title;
        }
        $new_crumb_array[] = $new_crumb;
    endforeach;
endif;

return $new_crumb_array;
}
```